# Should I create a new controller in cakephp

Tags: cakephp

I'm new in CakePhp but experienced in CodeIgniter. I created a controller in "WelcomeController.php" in controller directory and run the page. I got two errors
 1. Error: The view for WelcomeController::index() was not found.
 2. Error: Confirm you have created the file: C:\xampp\htdocs\myc\app\View\Welcome\index.ctp.

My question

1. Why I am getting this error even though I have supplied index() function?
2. In codeigniter we may not create a directory for a view. I don't want to create a directory "Welcome" in view. I there any provision provided?

Comment: We need a view file to render page view. If you don't like to render or display page means you wants to use that function or action, then you can easily prevent rendering view as '$this->autoRender = false'. If you set autoRender to false, you will not get 1st error.

Comment: your question is "Should I create a new controller in cakephp", but your problem is with views... it's kind of confusing

Comment: Sounds like you want to use the pages controller - You would ordinarily _only_ edit [home.ctp](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/tree/2.4.7/app/View/Pages) to change your home page contents, and _only_ create view files in that folder to access your `/pages/<page_name>`. You don't need a specific controller, or controller action, to action to do that. Unless you disable it, CakePHP will [render the view corresponding to the controller-action by default](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#Controller::render).

Answer (score 1):

In Cakephp you have to create view for function or here it called action. In your case, Create index.ctp on App->View->Welcome folder. This [Getting Start](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started.html)
will give you a basic idea.

Comment: That means if I've 3 functions in a controller class then I've to create 3 different .ctp files?

Comment: Not actually, it depends on what you wants to do. Cakephp is a very powerfull and flexible. Its gives you a lots of options depending on your need.

Answer (score 1):

1) You're getting that error because your missing the view, not the controller function. To fix, do what the error suggested:

> Confirm you have created the file: C:\xampp\htdocs\myc\app\View\Welcome\index.ctp.

2) "I don't want to create a directory "Welcome" in view. I there any provision provided?".
Not really... I mean, no if you want that action to have a correspondent view to put the content. Otherwise you can use `$this->autoRender = false` to not show anything... But that'll mean the url localhost/welcomes/index will be blank.

I recommend you read the basics as Fazal said. I know every framework can give us "quirks" and we end up expecting every other framework to work the same way we are used to, but try to adapt to the cake-way.

Btw, should be "WelcomesController", according to cake [conventions](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-conventions.html#controller-conventions)

Comment: Please tell me then how should I place the landing page. Like Home page, Contact Page, About us.

Comment: Take a look at this http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/pages-controller.html. Or also, you can search for that with "static pages cakephp" to look for examples (if the first link doesn't suit you)

Comment: I want to place my static pages in one directory like "static" in view  directory. Now how come is it possible as CakePhp find one pageview directory for one function of controller.

Comment: read the link, it does what you want. And please read the basics.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that you have all the files and directories necessary for the modal, controller and view to link up correctly i.e.: Create the folder called welcome(s) in your views directory with an index.ctp file. This should get rid of that error.

Check out this brilliant blog tutorial: [Link](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started.html#blog-tutorial-adding-a-layer)